Nuxtjs/i18n without detectBrowserLanguage, with cookie support. How to efficiently write custom handler?
I'm using nuxtjs/i18n for language handling. I do not want to use browser detection for language. I've spent so much time to write a custom solution but there are always some hiccups.
I get stuck on first load since it first loads a default language then it changes to the one that's written in the cookie. It's a visible change for a user.
I tried multiple times to do a middleware solutions of some sorts but I fail because I can't write setLocale outside of setup().
This is the current solution I have.
app.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>

const { locale, setLocale } = useI18n()

const cookie = useCookie('alprom_language')

setLocale(cookie.value || 'bs')

</script>

Please lead me the right way and be patient. Any recommendations?
